# If the key name is already registered, add the values instead of replacing old one - PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to check how many events are booked for a certain time frame. So, I am trying to create an array with `time_stamp` as an array and `space value` as a value as follows:

**$data**

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 7
            [start] => 2019-06-30
            [end] => 2019-06-30
            [start_time] => 11:00:00
            [end_time] => 12:00:00
            [hall_space] => 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 9
            [start] => 2019-06-30
            [end] => 2019-06-30
            [start_time] => 11:00:00
            [end_time] => 12:00:00
            [hall_space] => 2
        )

)
</pre
```

So, creating array

```
$booked = array();
foreach($data as $dk => $dv){
                $time_stamp = strtotime($dv->start.' '.$dv->start_time).'_'.strtotime($dv->end.' '.$dv->end_time).'_'.$dk;
                $booked[$time_stamp] = $dv->rink_space;
}
```

So, here it is storing data like:

```
<pre>Array
(
    [1561892400_1561896000_0] => 2
    [1561892400_1561896000_1] => 2
)
</pre>
```

But, if i remove this part `.'_'.$dk` it replace the first index with the second one and save only one index as follows:

```
<pre>Array
(
    [1561892400_1561896000] => 2
)
</pre>
```

In this case, if same index appears, instead of replacing, I want to add the values so that the values becomes 4 instead of 2 like follows:

```
<pre>Array
(
    [1561892400_1561896000] => 4
)
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to approach it, a simple one is to check if the value exists (using `isset()`) and if it does, just add it in, if it doesn't then set it to the new value...

```
$booked = array();
foreach($data as $dk => $dv){
    $time_stamp = strtotime($dv->start.' '.$dv->start_time).'_'.strtotime($dv->end.' '.$dv->end_time);
    if ( isset($booked[$time_stamp]) )  {
        $booked[$time_stamp] += $dv->rink_space;
    }
    else {
        $booked[$time_stamp] = $dv->rink_space;
    }
}
```

(I've removed the end of the timestamp which is what I assume your trying to avoid having to do).